# TypeError Not all Arguments Converted During String Formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, formatting, typeerror

I'm trying to loop through the Numbers List and on each iteration I want to check if the added Number were even or single but Unfortunately I've got this error.

```
ask = int(input("How Many Numbers You Want to Print ? : "))
numbers = []
for i in range(0, ask):
    x = input("What's Number " + str(i+1) + " : ")
    numbers.append(x)

for y in numbers:
    if (y % 2) == 0:
        print("Even Numbers : " + y)
```

But When I run my code its Giving me :

```
How Many Numbers You Want to Print ? : 3
What's Number 1 : 15
What's Number 2 : 16
What's Number 3 : 13
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Desktop/Python_Projects/network_scanner/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    if y % 2 == 0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Change `x = input("What's Number " + str(i+1) + " : ")` to `x = int(input("What's Number " + str(i+1) + " : "))`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are ending up with this error is because `y` is a string, and you cannot use the modulus (`%`) function with strings. There are two ways around this:

1. Change `if (y % 2) == 0:` to `if (int(y) % 2) == 0:`. This will turn `y` into an integer, so that the modulus function would work.
2. Change `x = input(...)` to `x = int(input(...))`. This would turn `x` (the input value) into an integer, so that the modulus function would work.

   Although, you will then find yourself with this error:

   ```
   TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
   ```

   A way around this is to change `print("Even Numbers : " + y)` to `print("Even Numbers : " + str(y))`. The `str()` function converts `y` from an integer into a string.

Comment: It's easier to have `print` do the conversion to `str` for you: `print("Even Numbers :" + y)`. On that note, you wrote that *"the `print()` function only accepts strings."*, which is incorrect, so I've removed it for you.

Comment: Just to be clear, you can use the `%` operator on strings, but it's not for modulus, it's for old-style string formatting.